Reverend dad looks for runaway prostitue daughter in big city; 'Sunday' in the title
This may have been a tv movie I saw somewhere on Tv a year or so ago, a father who I think is a small town Reverend played by a big actor, thought George C. Scott or Marlon Brando but no movie in their filmography that could be it, the actor was that type of character. He goes to I think San Fransisco to the seedy underworld searching for his daughter

Sounds like George C. Scott's Hardcore, (1979), though he played a businessman, not a Reverend, and his daughter was making porn films, not being a prostitute.

Jake Van Dorn is a businessman from the American heartland who shares
  strong Calvinist convictions with most of his countrymen. His teenage
  daughter is missing from her church youth convention trip to
  California and Van Dorn hires a private investigator to find her. The
  result of the investigation is his daughter is spotted in a cheap
  X-rated movie. Van Dorn decides to bring her back personally and
  during the quest he becomes familiar with the pornographic underworld.


that could have been it but I thought for sure Sunday was in the tile but I was pretty sure it was Geroge C. scott so I think maybe I was wrong on the Sunday bit. the bit about missing from her church youth convention may be where I was getting confused. I will try and find the movie and check it out, thanks

Is it possible you've mixed up two movies?
